# How to get posts from people I follow and my posts in php and mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I have table

1. answers(aid,user_id,...) - posts table
2. users (userid,name,...)
3. followers(user_one,user_two) - where user_one is the follower and user_two is the followed by person.

I need to show posts from people I follow and my posts using php and mysql in my home feed.But currently it is not working as expected.**Each posts is showing 7 times.**

curent select query

```
<?php

    $my_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
     $sql_query = "SELECT * FROM answers left join users on users.userid = answers.user_id LEFT join followers on followers.user_one = answers.user_id WHERE answers.user_id= '$my_id' ORDER BY answers.date_created DESC";  
?>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what is not working exactly?

Comment: why the `[regex]` tag?

Comment: select * from answers where user_id in (select user_two where user_one=xxx);

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen each post is showing 7 times

Comment: @iamnoten could you please elaborate the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Didn't see you also want to return your posts. Try below sql:

```
     select * from answers, users, (select user_one user_id from followers where user_two='$my_id' union select '$my_id' user_id) a where answers.user_id=users.user_id and answers.user_id=a.user_id;
```

---

There is error in your sql: SELECT * FROM answers left join users on users.userid = answers.user_id LEFT join followers on followers.user_one = answers.user_id WHERE answers.user_id= '$my_id' ORDER BY answers.date_created DESC".

the second left join should be followers.user_two=ansers.user_id, and the where statement should be followers.user_one='$my_id';

Comment: Thanks , it helped me show posts from others I follow.. but the problem is I need to show my posts. also

Comment: @iamnoten Now the problem is it shows posts from me , and posts from other user if they followed me not i followed.. please do help

Comment: here user_one =>the person who follows a user , current logged_in user & user_two => the user followed by the current user

Comment: Thanks I fixed , there was a small error in the solution

Comment: ,corrected solution below , select * from answers, users, (select user_two user_id from followers where user_one='$my_id' union select '$my_id' user_id) a where answers.user_id=users.userid and answers.user_id=a.user_id

Comment: Your syntax is non ideal, because you have commas in the `FROM` clause.  You should try to rewrite this query using explicit joins if possible.

Answer (score 1):

One option here is to phrase your query as a union of two queries.  The first half of the union below finds all posts given by people you follow.  The second half of the union finds all of your posts.

```
SELECT a.*
FROM answers a
INNER JOIN followers f
    ON (a.user_id = f.user_two AND f.user_one = $my_id)
UNION ALL
SELECT a.* FROM answers WHERE user_id = $my_id;
```

I'm not a PHP person, but hopefully you can easily adapt the above query into your code.